# How to 'checked' the matched day from two array set

Tags: php, array-intersect

I need to match the day by checking the checkbox from database with the week array. Here is my resources:

**$weekDay**

```
$weekDay=array("1"=>"Mon","2"=>"Tue","3"=>"Wed","4"=>"Thu","5"=>"Fri","6"=>"Sat","7"=>"Sun");
```

**$opDay**

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 )
```

So I write :

```
foreach($weekDay as $key=>$val){
$inDay = array_intersect($weekDay,$opDays);        
echo "<label><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"exc_opd[]\" value=\"{$key}\" ".(($inDay)? '"checked"':" " )."/>&nbsp;{$val}</label>&nbsp;";                    
}
```

As per the function I expect the checkbox which matches the `$opDay` would `checked`. And the loop will continue with unchecked boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I come up with this solution. Might not be the best but it is working. Any suggestion for my knowledge will be appreciated.

```
foreach($weekDay as $key=>$val){
$inDay = array_intersect_key($weekDay,array_flip($opDays));        
if($inDay[$key]){
    echo "<label><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"exc_opd[]\" value=\"{$key}\" checked/>&nbsp;$val</label>&nbsp;";       
}else{
    echo "<label><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"exc_opd[]\" value=\"{$key}\"/>&nbsp;$val</label>&nbsp;";       
    }
}
```